# Can you declare a constant object in a function?

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, uninitialized-constant, fastled

One semester of Comp Sci under my belt, here goes nothing.

I need to call a constant int to use for the number of LEDs are in a strip for FastLED. Long story short, I'm trying to replace...

```
    #include "FastLED.h"
    #define NUM_LEDS_RT 174
    #define DATA_PIN_RT 6 
    #define CLOCK_PIN_RT 5
    ...
    CRGB led[NUM_LEDS_RT + NUM_LEDS_MID + NUM_LEDS_LF + NUM_LEDS_FIRE];
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, DATA_PIN_RT, CLOCK_PIN_RT, BGR> (led, NUM_LEDS_RT);
```

With my own library that I made creating a struct for the LED strip, holding the above information, seeded by the driver file for the program. Everything should be in working order, but I can't get past this first error. For example, the object containing my data is build by...

```
    Strip::Strip(int data, int clock, int num)
    {
       #define DATA_Pin data
       #define CLOCK_Pin clock
       #define NUM_LEDS num
    }
```

and is seeded by the driver as...

```
    Strip RIGHT(6, 5, 174);
```

Simply stated, is there a way to call an object to have constant values? The error that occurs says that RIGHT.name is not a constant variable, and receive "Led.cpp:39: error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 3)" or some variation of that.

Please help! Let me know if you need any further information. Thank you!

EDIT: Added more code for reference:
Strip Class

```
    #ifndef Strip_h
    #define Strip_h
    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include <String>
    #include "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/FastLED.h"

    class Strip
    {
    public: 
Strip(int data, int clock, int num);

    private:
    int DATA_Pin;
int CLOCK_Pin;
int NUM_LEDS;
    };

    #endif

    #include "Strip.h"


    Strip::Strip(int data, int clock, int num)
    {
         DATA_Pin = data;
         CLOCK_Pin = clock;
         NUM_LEDS = num;
    }
```

Led Class

```
    #ifndef Led_h
    #define Led_h
    include "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/FastLED.h"
    #include "Strip.h"

    class Led
    {
    public: 
        Led(const Strip& name);
        Led(const Strip& name, const Strip& name2);
        Led(const Strip& name, const Strip& name2, const Strip& name3);
        Led(const Strip& name, const Strip& name2, const Strip& name3, const Strip& name4);                        

    private:

    };

    #endif

    Led::Led(const Strip& const Strip&, const Strip& name2, const Strip& name3, const Strip& name4)
    {
        CRGB led[name.NUM_LEDS + name2.NUM_LEDS + name3.NUM_LEDS + name4.NUM_LEDS];

        FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, name.DATA_Pin, name.CLOCK_Pin, BGR>(led, name.NUM_LEDS);
        FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, name2.DATA_Pin, name2.CLOCK_Pin, BGR>(led, name.NUM_LEDS, name.NUM_LEDS + name2.NUM_LEDS);
        FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, name3.DATA_Pin, name3.CLOCK_Pin, BGR>(led, name.NUM_LEDS + name2.NUM_LEDS, name.NUM_LEDS + name2.NUM_LEDS + name3.NUM_LEDS);
        FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, name4.DATA_Pin, name4.CLOCK_Pin, BGR>(led, name.NUM_LEDS + name2.NUM_LEDS + name3.NUM_LEDS, name.NUM_LEDS + name2.NUM_LEDS + name3.NUM_LEDS + name4.NUM_LEDS);
    }
```

Driver

```
    #include "Led.h"
    #include "MusicChip.h"
    #include "Shapes.h"
    #include "Strip.h"

      const Strip RIGHT(6, 5, 174);
      const Strip MID(4, 3, 200);
      const Strip LEFT(22, 23, 177);
      const Strip FIRE(10, 12, 97);

    void setup()
    {
      delay(1000); // Sanity Check, allows input to settle  
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Led running(RIGHT, MID, LEFT, FIRE);

      MusicChip MAIN(0, 8, 7); 
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `#define` - anywhere - every again (well, at least until you know what it does).  When you say `#define DATA_Pin data` it creates a preprocessor macro `DATA_Pin` - wherever else that's later used in the code `data` will be substituted; it does ***not*** add any functionality to the constructor.  Perhaps you mean to assign to some data members?  That should be done in an initialiser list: `Strip::Strip(int xdata, int xclock, int xnum) : data(xdata), clock(xclock), num(xnum) { }`

Comment: Where you say "call" I think you mean some other verb.  But I haven't figured out which.  Is it "declare"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just trying to provide an example of what I was trying to accomplish. I have it in my project as:

`Strip::Strip(int data, int clock, int num)
{
  DATA_Pin = data;
  CLOCK_Pin = clock;
  NUM_LEDS = num;
}`

Comment: Yes, declare! Or initialize.

Comment: Hi, @user3758719, and welcome to stackoverflow!  You can still [edit] your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @user3758719: ok - that looks a bit better ;-).  So, your definition for `RIGHT` looks correct... you better show us the full defintion for `Strip` and the code surrounding `Strip RIGHT(6, 5, 174);`.  Separately, don't use all-uppercase multi-letter identifiers for anything *except* preprocessor macros - if you don't partition your identifier usage, it's hard to know if "RIGHT" is being replaced with some other source code.

Comment: I added the rest of my code above. I will change the all cap variables now.

Comment: Thank you Drew! I'll do that now!

Comment: Since no one else has mentioned this, I will: C++ is an awful language. It is an especially awful language for new programmers. And it is an unbelievably awful language for new programmers attempting to learn it on their own. Might I suggest you consider something like [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), [Python](https://www.python.org/), or [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) instead? Heck, even Standard ML or [Haskell](http://haskell.org) is probably easier to learn, and a heck of a lot more powerful.

Comment: C++ is the language that I have had the most experience with, and I believe that it is the only language compatible with Arduino(?). I have had some interest in digging around Python, and would love to pick up Java. I'll definitely look into it!

Comment: @dfeuer: that's about as inappropriate as comment on Stackoverflow get... many of us would vehemently disagree, and discussions of it are banned, so it's a cheap shot.  C++ is quite easy to learn if you have a good book or teacher.  I taught myself from an online guide initially, but knew C and many other languages first.

Comment: @Retro: you are passing `name.DATA_Pin` etc as template arguments... they are not compile-time const (they'd need to be marked with `constexpr`, and you'd need `constexpr` constructors and lots of other complicated things.  I suggest you do not make `addLeds` a template, and pass all the values it needs as function arguments/parameters.  When you know C++ really well, you can worry about extra efficiency.

Comment: Thank you Tony! I'll give it a try tomorrow. Gotta work for a living. I'll get back to you shortly!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for creating a const object is as you have it:

```
const Strip RIGHT(6, 5, 174);
```

Note that you do not need to actually have a const object in order to call a function that takes const reference.  You can just pass non-const objects and they are treated as const for the purposes of that function call.

Yuu mention something about template problems. It's hard to say since you didn't post the error messages along with where they occurred, but this code here is hopelessly broken:

```
FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, name.DATA_Pin, name.CLOCK_Pin, BGR>(led, name.NUM_LEDS);
```

and the other lines after it. Template arguments must be resolved at compile-time. You cannot place variables in the list of template arguments like you have done.

Comment: I'm sorry for posting the above code. What I meant to ask is how to accomplish that sort of constant variable without using #define.

I am using the FastLED library, which has a function called 'addLed' in order to create a virtual array of LEDs which then control the physical ones' color. When trying to use that function with anything else besides the #define macro, it gives me the above error message. Through some research tonight, I believe that it is due to the fact that I am not creating the object with constant int's.

Comment: If you want help with an error message, please post the exact error message along with which line you got it on.

Comment: `const Strip RIGHT(6, 5, 174);` is the correct syntax to create a `const` `Strip`

Comment: " 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'const Strip&'" is the error message now, as it relates to the code above. 

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That error probably refers to `Led::Led(const Strip& const Strip&, const Strip& name2, const Strip& name3, const Strip& name4)`. You should indicate which line of code errors are coming from.  The error is that "const Strip& const Strip&" is not a valid declarator . I think you meant `const Strip& name` there.

Comment: Yes that is the correct error line, sorry for the omission. After making that change, the first error message has now returned. The message reads: **"no matching function for call to 'CFastLED::addLeds(CRGB[(int)(((((int)name.Strip::NUM_LEDS) + ((int)name2.Strip::NUM_LEDS)) + ((int)name3.Strip::NUM_LEDS)) + ((int)name4.Strip::NUM_LEDS))], const int&)' "** from the first line that starts with FastLED.addLeds<...> (led, name.NUM_LEDS);

Comment: we could be here all night doing this... clearly you know next to nothing about C++; it's not a good idea to guess dozens of lines of code and then have no idea how to read error messages.  My advice would be to learn some basic C++ first. Then, in your program start with some code that compiles successfully and then gradually add in the additions you want to make.

Comment: Definitely don't understand how to read error messages... yet! But I'll keep chipping away at it. Thank you for you're patience and input.

Comment: I think the general idea is start by making simpler mistakes :) If you write a whole library by yourself, you'll have a lot of debugging to get started with, which probably isn't that instructive

Comment: @chrisb2244 Kind of what I have been doing. I have already written out this program once, but am trying to take it from a huge block of text to several smaller libraries to which I can add more features and what not. The problem is just this stupid constant thing.

Comment: I already said - the problem is you're trying to use variables as template arguments. That doesn't work (making them `const` is no difference).